# Google Sheets Table Charts -wrap text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table chart with a lot of text in one of my cells that I am referencing and instead of wrapping the text as it is in the source cell it just puts a scroll bar in the table chart. Does anyone know if there is a way of wrapping the text in the graph? I have been looking online but it seems to be is very little documentation regarding these charts.

[image]

Comment: You can change the angle of the text which might help but I don't think you can wrap it.  If you want to increase the chances of getting a good answer I would provide and image of the chart and the code used to create it.  Most of us probably don't do charts everyday so we could probably use some assistance from you to jog what ever memory we might have of such a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I just added an image to maybe make it a bit clearer. As you can see that silly scroll bar comes up when the text is longer than the window. But if I then need to for example need to print it then it doesn't work as you cannot see the whole text.

Comment: What's your reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: It came from that I have a slides document embedded on a website. This document has linked objects like graphs and tables copied from google slides. When the slide is embedded I don't seems to be able to update as usual tools>Linked objects, the buttons are greyed out. I found an app script that enables me to update graphs in an embedded slides document but I haven't be able to find another way to update tables other than making them into table graphs. I am having form response sent to a google sheet, then I process the data in sheets which I then display in slides.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a half answer but this is what I did if someone is curious...

I split my text over several rows and then made a graph of that. The formula I used was one I found here https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-text-after-every-nth-word-in-sheets/

=TRANSPOSE(split(REGEXREPLACE(B4,"(([a-zA-Z'‘’:.,_?!”“)(}{][]+\s){15})", "$1"),""))

[image: how it looks]